# How to refresh a variable without losing its value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, pygame

recently I started doing Snake in python. I came up wiht the idea to the movement that snake remembers its last position. I have to refresh a variable called body to make it work, because I called it before the mainloop started. When the snake eats an apple, the body variable should extend and I don't want to lose its extended value. Can you please help me?
This is my code:

```
import pygame, math, random

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,640))
pygame.display.set_caption('Snake')


score = 0


x, y = 320,320
dirUp, dirDown = False, False
dirLeft, dirRight = False, False
body = [(x, y)]
snakeImg = [pygame.image.load('snakeblock.png') for i in range(len(body))]





squares = []
for i in range(640):
    if i % 32 == 0:
        squares.append(i)
food = pygame.image.load('fruit.png')
foodx,foody = random.choice(squares), random.choice(squares)

def isCollision(obsX, obsY, x, y):
    return math.sqrt(math.pow(obsX - x, 2) + math.pow(obsY - y, 2)) <= 0

def show_text():
    score_font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',32)
    score_text = score_font.render('Score: {}'.format(score), True, (255,255,255))
    screen.blit(score_text, (0,0))

running = True
i = 0
while running:
    i += 1
    body = body
    pygame.time.Clock().tick(10)
    screen.fill((0,128,0))

    if x > 608 or x < 0:
        running = False
    elif y > 608 or y < 0:
        running = False

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                dirUp = True
                dirLeft, dirDown, dirRight = False, False, False
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                dirDown = True
                dirUp, dirLeft, dirRight = False, False, False
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                dirRight = True
                dirUp, dirDown, dirLeft = False, False, False
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                dirLeft = True
                dirUp, dirDown, dirRight = False, False, False

    if dirUp:
        y -= 32
    elif dirDown:
        y += 32
    elif dirRight:
        x += 32
    elif dirLeft:
        x -= 32

    for i in range(len(body)):
        if isCollision(foodx,foody,x,y):
            foodx, foody = random.choice(squares), random.choice(squares)
            score += 1
            print( body)
        screen.blit(food, (foodx, foody))
        screen.blit(snakeImg[i], (x, y))

    show_text()

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Make `body` a global variable. Just add one line before declaring `body` i.e. `global body`. So do not need to reassign it every time in your main loop.

Comment: ```Global``` doesn't work like that. Also my mainloop isn't in a function.

Comment: When you say you want to extend `body` do you want to update the `x` and `y` in it, or to have it extend like `[(x1, y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3)]` for each body segment?

Comment: I want to extend it like ```[(x1,y1), (x2y2), (x3y3)]```.

Comment: You could trying appending new body segments to `body` by doing something like `body.append((x, y))` and remove the `body = body` line in your code.

Comment: Just FYI, you don't need to tag your text editor in a question unless the question directly pertains to the editor itself.

Comment: OK. I tagged it because it's popular but from now on ill won't do that.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that i couldn't modify the whole list at once. Instead i did something like this:

```
while running:

    last_pos = (body[-1][0], body[-1][1])
    body[0] = (x,y)
    for i in range(1,len(body)):
        body[i] = last_pos
```